# HUAWEI MediaPad M5 Lite 10 returns screenLayout SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE

Tags: android, layout, screen, tablet, huawei-mobile-services

How come this tablet wants to be screen layout size large? I have other tablets with worse resolution that display XLarge.. Our current application only displays in "tablet mode" if this method returns screen layout size XLarge. So, this tablet is displayed in phone mode since it returns size Large. Is there a way around this? Can I get this tablet to return size XLarge so it can be displayed in "tablet mode" (since it is actually a tablet)?

Method Information (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration#screenLayout):

screenLayout()

public int screenLayout

Bit mask of overall layout of the screen. Currently there are four fields:

The SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK bits define the overall size of the screen. They may be one of SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL, SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL, SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE, or SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE.

The SCREENLAYOUT_LONG_MASK defines whether the screen is wider/taller than normal. They may be one of SCREENLAYOUT_LONG_NO or SCREENLAYOUT_LONG_YES.

The SCREENLAYOUT_LAYOUTDIR_MASK defines whether the screen layout is either LTR or RTL. They may be one of SCREENLAYOUT_LAYOUTDIR_LTR or SCREENLAYOUT_LAYOUTDIR_RTL.

The SCREENLAYOUT_ROUND_MASK defines whether the screen has a rounded shape. They may be one of SCREENLAYOUT_ROUND_NO or SCREENLAYOUT_ROUND_YES.

See Supporting Multiple Screens for more information.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration#screenLayout for reference